# user chooses one of two images without GUI

Tags: matlab, user-input, matlab-figure

I have a binary image `Bimg` and I nat the user to select between it and the complementry. I have used subplots to present the user with the two images:

```
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(Bimg);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(~Bimg);
```

Can I take a click input from the user without building a GUI?
can I somehow use `ginput()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply bind a callback function to the `ButtonDownFcn` of the image object. We can combine this callback function with `waitfor` to make this similar to a dialog for the user to select one of two images.

```
function clicked = imgdlg(Bimg)
    hfig = dialog();
    hax1 = subplot(1,2,1, 'Parent', hfig);
    him1 = imshow(Bimg, 'Parent', hax1);
    title('Normal')

    hax2 = subplot(1,2,2, 'Parent', hfig);
    him2 = imshow(~Bimg, 'Parent', hax2);
    title('Complement')

    % Assign a tag to each of the images corresponding to what it is.
    % Also have "callback" execute when either image is clicked
    set([him1, him2], ...
        {'Tag'}, {'normal', 'complement'}, ...
        'ButtonDownFcn', @callback)

    drawnow

    % Wait for the UserData of the figure to change
    waitfor(hfig, 'Userdata');

    % Get the value assigned to the UserData of the figure
    clicked = get(hfig, 'Userdata');

    % Delete the figure
    delete(hfig);

    function callback(src, evnt)
        % Store the tag of the clicked object in the UserData of the figure
        set(gcbf, 'UserData', get(src, 'tag'))
    end
end
```